# About Apple's review policy with login in apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am making an iPhone App and one part of the app is only visible for the users that are login. The problem is that the user who can login into the app are not all the world. I select them and put it in my server.

Can I publish in appStore my app with this kind of login? Because there isn't any option to register inside of the app.

Thank you soo much

David.

Answer (score 2):

Apple will usually accept such applications but you need to provide test credentials when you submit to the app store so that they can go through their validation tests for the parts of you app that are only accessible via login.

Comment: Good point! I will send the app to the store and check what apple says me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Usually you put the test credential in the additional info or comments section in the submission form, you can do this on first submission to avoid having to go through a whole cycle of refusal and re-submission.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think that I will do the second option :)

Answer (score 1):

If its only a specific portion of your app i dont see a reason why not, but Apple keeps surprising me everytime :-)

It greatly depends on the kind of part you're trying to hide. If its a "members only" zone and you're allowing access only to paying members, you have to do it through In-App Purchases or Apple won't approve it. If its just a "special login for staff members" , for example , i don't think there would be much of a problem .

Shai.

Comment: It is more like a developer zone. And only the developer can go inside (with the private login) to change contents of the app inside of it. Well, I think that I am going to try and if they reject it I ask them. Thank you!

Comment: I believe no problem with that whatsoever. As jbat100 said, don't forget to provide credentials for testing.